Heat exchange speed of two liquids separately vs their mixture
I'm quite oblivious about basic high school physics, so pardon my misuse of terms and inability to google the answer.
I want to solve a puzzle that I face in my daily routine. Suppose I want to make a cup of tea with milk, but I want to start drinking it after $N$ minutes. Which way will preserve the hottest tea: I take a cup with cold milk and (1) I boil the water, pour it into the cup and wait $N$ minutes, or (2) I boil the water, wait $N$ minutes and pour it into the cup.
The only thing I managed to google is Newton's law of cooling, stating that the heat-transfer rate is linearly proportional to the temperature difference between two mediums. So I suppose the answer is "no difference", however I vaguely remember the university courses referring to some quadratic or even higher order dependence on the temperature difference, but I just fail to find them and the context in which they are applied

The good news is, this is an easy test to make yourself, requiring no physics training.  We would be interested to hear your findings.

@RC_23 Yeah, I've run an experiment, you can see my answer :)

Nice work! You may be able to get more information on this topic on the cooking or culinary stack exchange.

It looks like the 2 procedures don't provide the same result. In what follows, it's assumed that:

initial milk temperature is the same as the environment temperature, $T_{env}$
no heat or work exchange with the external environment occurs while mixing milk and water, so that the internal energy is constant; at the end of this process, thermal equilibrium is established;
internal energy for each medium may be written as $U_k = m_k c_k T_k$, for $k = m:\text{milk or } w: \text{water}$
heat flux during the rest time is proportional to the difference of the temperature (assumed to be uniform) of the system and the temperature of the external environment; no work is done on the system and thus the energy balance reads,
$$m c \frac{d T}{dt} = - h S (T - T_{env}) \ .$$

If I haven't messed things up, the final temperature at the end of the first procedure is
$$T_{A,fin} = T_{env} + \frac{T_{boil} - T_{env}}{1+\frac{m_m c_m}{m_w c_w }} \text{exp} \left[ -\frac{hS_A}{m_w c_w}\frac{1}{1+\frac{m_m c_m}{m_w c_w } }\Delta t\right] \ ,$$
while temperature at the end of the second procedure reads
procedure is
$$T_{B,fin} = T_{env} + \frac{T_{boil} - T_{env}}{1+\frac{m_m c_m}{m_w c_w }} \text{exp} \left[ -\frac{hS_B}{m_w c_w}\Delta t\right] \ .$$
Even in this simple model, the constant of proportionality in the heat flux $hS_k$ may differ in these two procedures, since the interface surface may vary (when you mix together milk and water before waiting, the system has more mass and likely larger interface surface with the external environment, increasing the heat flux).
Once we know this, let's forget about this (and remember that what we follows assumes $hS_A = hS_B$). If this is the case, the two expressions of the final temperature are similar, with the only difference in the factor $\frac{1}{1+\frac{m_m c_m}{m_w c_w } } < 1$ in the exponential.
Thus, for the same values of the same variables, the absolute value of the exponent in case A is larger than the one of case B. Since the exponent is negative, and the factor of the exponential is positive as well, it follows that
$$T_{A,fin} > T_{B,fin} \ .$$

I've run an experiment, you can see my answer. Your calculation seems correct, at least the inequality is :) Thanks for the formulas

Nice that the conclusion matches. If someone has time, and a thermometer, it would be nice to see some more detailed measurements

So I ran my own experiment, and tried to make it as rigorous as my kitchen allows it. I don't have any way to measure temperatures exactly, but I have kitchen scales
The setup:

3 identical cups, of room temperature
20 grams of fridge-cold milk poured into 2 of the cups simultaneously
water is boiled to the maximum bubbling
80 grams of water is poured into 1 of the milk cups, and other 80 grams into 1 clean cup
I put all three cups into a closet, so they were somewhat isolated from the apartment's air flow and stove's residual heat
the cups were not covered, and placed at significant distance from each other

After 5 minutes I took all the cups, and poured the hot water cup into the cold milk cup and mixed with a toothpick
After immediately tasting it, the premixed solution was way hotter. The post-mixed one was barely above "warm"
P.S. And physics aside, the premixed liquid was also tastier, maybe the milk sugar (lactose) had some time to "caramelize" in the heat, bringing a very creamy taste :)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
